# Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{q^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, harmonic-numbers

How can I prove that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{q^n}=\frac{q}{q-1}\log(\frac{q}{q-1})$$

($H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$, $|q|>1$).

Comment: Hint: write $q/(q-1)$ as $1/(1-1/q)$ then expand each factor of the right-hand side as a power series in $1/q$.  This would verify the identity for $|q| > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Look at the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{q^n}$ as fractions.
2. Your equation fail if $|q| > 1$ is false.